# Using web-worker in the library, but the chunk file can not be found in react application

Tags: javascript, web-worker, webpack-5

There are two separate repo:

**Library repo**

**React Web application**

---

library provide 2 functions

- func1 without using web-worker
- func2 using web-worker

```js
// func2
export const func2 = () => {
   //.....
   const worker = new Worker(new URL('./web-worker/worker.ts', import.meta.url));
   //.....
}
```

bundle files from webpack5
[image]

then import it in react web application
[image]

**func1** works fine

### but got this error when I calling the **func2**

[image]

below is webpack config for the **library**

```js
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.ts$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: "/",
    library: {
      type: 'umd',
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
};
 
module.exports = config
```

Comment: I suspect that the problem might be that func2 is trying to resolve `./web-worker/worker.ts` although it should look for the compiled version of it. I don't think webpack will compile that element specifically, because it is not resolved by it (webpack) at compile time but rather by the browser itself at runtime.